# Local storage gets cleared on Page refresh in redux token auth

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am using react-token-auth for login purpose.The login part is successful and the token gets stored in local storage.But when i refresh the page data in local storage becomes undefined.

I have seen the issues page in their git-hub there they have mentioned to handle the below lines in back end. I don't have much exposure in backend.

If anyone has faced this issue already pls tell me how you have sorted it.

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
      allow do
        origins '*'
        resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :delete, :put, :patch, :options, :head], :expose  => ['uid', 'client', 'expiry', 'access-token', 'token-type']
      end
    end
```

Comment: did you found any solution on this. I am also facing the similar issue, but I am not using redux.

Answer (score 0):

LocalStorage will persist across page refreshes, so I think there might be something wrong with your localstorage code.

should be like this to set:

```
localStorage.setItem('somekey', 'someval');
```

and to retrieve:

```
localStorage.getItem('somekey');
```

Please verify also that you can see the correct value stored in your Application -> Local Storage tab in Chrome Dev Tools.

EDIT:

If all the above seems fine, perhaps you are overwriting the value yourself! Console.log out any calls to localstorage.setItem.

Comment: I think the OP's problem is  when doing hard refresh the local storage value gets undefined

Comment: The OP does not mention hard refresh, and besides, a hard refresh will not delete LocalStorage values

Comment: But one of the issues mentioned in explains the problem of data getting undefined during hard refresh
https://github.com/kylecorbelli/redux-token-auth/issues/39